# Applying the list function to nested generators in itertools.groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

How does the `list` function behave when applied to nested generators? In the following code snippet, I find the behaviour rather puzzling: it seems that `list` consumes most of the nested generators apart from the last one which still keeps one element:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
>>> for k, g in list(groupby(xs)):
...     print(k, list(g))
1 []
2 []
3 [3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a call to list will not consume a nested iterator/generator.

The behavior is peculiar to [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and is described in the docs:

> The returned group is itself an iterator that **shares** the underlying
>   iterable with `groupby()`. Because the source is shared, when the
>   `groupby()` object is advanced, **the previous group is no longer visible**.

[*Emphasis mine*]

If you give a look to the Python source equivalent of `itertools.groupby` provided in the docs, this becomes more explanatory:

```
class groupby(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable, key=None):
        if key is None:
            key = lambda x: x
        self.keyfunc = key

        self.it = iter(iterable) # shared iterator

        self.tgtkey = self.currkey = self.currvalue = object()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        while self.currkey == self.tgtkey:
            self.currvalue = next(self.it)    # Exit on StopIteration
            self.currkey = self.keyfunc(self.currvalue)
        self.tgtkey = self.currkey
        return (self.currkey, self._grouper(self.tgtkey))

    def _grouper(self, tgtkey):
        while self.currkey == tgtkey:
            yield self.currvalue
            self.currvalue = next(self.it)    # Exit on StopIteration
            self.currkey = self.keyfunc(self.currvalue)
```

The last `[3]` which shows up in your result is `self.currvalue` (yielded by `_grouper`) which was already assigned from the previous call to next on the `groupby` object.

In order to keep the results of each group, you should store them in a list, and that without consuming the `groupby` object all at once.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer! I should have checked more carefully the documentation :-)